# extjs contextmenu click error - method not found... but looking in wrong controller

Tags: extjs, controller, contextmenu

how do I point this menu item click to launch a method in a controller.
The item click is being hit successfully but the error message states No method named "onDownloadTopdayRecapContextButton" on ExtApplication4.view.main.MainController.  That is the problem, you can see the view's controller is portalRealtime-portalRealtime.

So somehow its pointing to the wrong controller.  Can someone show me what I am doing wrong?

menu code

```
var contextMenuTopday = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
items: [{
    text: 'Download Topday Recap',
    iconCls: 'downloadIcon',
    listeners: {
        click: 'onDownloadTopdayRecapContextButton'
    }
```

grid menu is held in

```
Ext.define('ExtApplication4.view.portalRealtime.PortalRealtime', {
extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

xtype: 'app-portalRealtime',

itemId: 'portalRealtimeItemID',

requires: [
    'ExtApplication4.view.portalRealtime.PortalRealtimeController',
    'Ext.form.action.StandardSubmit'
],

controller: 'portalRealtime-portalRealtime',

title: 'Main Portal',

layout: {
    type: 'vbox'
},

items: [
//i deleted some grid code here
            collapsible: true,
            collapseDirection: 'left',
            listeners: {

                itemcontextmenu: function (view, rec, node, index, e) {
                    e.stopEvent();                    
                    contextMenuTopday.showAt(e.getXY());
                    return false;
                }
{
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating the context menu outside of your view, so it does not inherit your controller.

**Before using the below code please scroll to the bottom of the answer for a better solution, but this hopefully shows what is the cause of your issue.**

*If this doesn't solve your issue, please comment and provide a more complete code example, and I will update my answer*

In these cases you can pass a controller manually, but you need to pass as a parent, as you get all kinds of problems if you re-use the same controller on multiple components (when you destroy one for example, it destroys the controller, leaving the other without)

So you could create from within your view like so:

```
Ext.define('ExtApplication4.view.portalRealtime.PortalRealtime', {
    initComponent:function(){
        this.callParent(arguments);
        this.contextMenuTopday = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
            controller:{
                parent: this.getController()
            },
            items: [{
                text: 'Download Topday Recap',
                iconCls: 'downloadIcon',
                listeners: {
                    click: 'onDownloadTopdayRecapContextButton'
                }
            }]
        });
    }
```

Then rather than use a variable to access the context menu you can access the contextMenuTopday property, as you are within a child item you may need to traverse to your actual view, the simplest way of doing this is via the up method available on components, you would need to make sure you include an xtype to do this:

```
Ext.define('ExtApplication4.view.portalRealtime.PortalRealtime', {
    xtype:'portalrealtime'
```

Then from within the context menu you can do:

```
itemcontextmenu: function (view, rec, node, index, e) {
    this.up('portalrealtime').contextMenuTopday.showAt(e.getXY());
}
```

## A better way

Best illustrated looking at this fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1qpn

Define your menu as its own class:

```
Ext.define('Example.ContextMenu', {
    xtype:'testmenu',
    extend:'Ext.menu.Menu',
    items: [{
            text: 'Download Topday Recap',
            iconCls: 'downloadIcon',
            listeners: {
                click: 'onDownloadTopdayRecapContextButton'
            }
        }]
    });
```

Use a method on your controller for the itemcontextmenu event (This is good anyway as it provides a better separation of concerns):
    itemcontextmenu: 'showContextMenu'

Then add a a few new methods to your `portalRealtime-portalRealtime` controller:

```
getContextMenu:function(){
    if(!this.contextMenu){
        this.contextMenu = this.getView().add({xtype:'testmenu'});
    }
    return this.contextMenu;
},
showContextMenu:function (view, rec, node, index, e) {
    // we can't use showAt now we have added this to our view, as it would be positioned relatively.
    this.getContextMenu().show().setPagePosition(e.getXY());

}
```

What we are doing here is adding the context menu to the view, so it inherits the controller (and a viewmodel if provided).

The best way to call methods on your controller for listeners/button handlers etc is to just specify the method name as a string i.e.:

```
listeners:{
    itemcontextmenu: 'showContextMenu'
}
```

This will automatically look up the responsible controller and use the correct method.

If you need to call from within a component you will find that `this.getController()` fails unless you call on the actual component the controller is attached to - i.e. you are calling from a child component. In these cases you can use `this.lookupController()` to find the inherited/responsible controller and then call any methods from here e.g. `this.lookupController().myMethod()`

Comment: thanks Theo, I am totally up for the BETTER WAY.  So I see I need to add a few methods as you described.  My question is where do I add these methods?... in the controller I am trying to hit? , and from the grid in the view, how do I launch the methods you are creating?

Comment: @solarissf I have updated the answer with some more info on this.

Comment: ok, so the methods in the controller get called... once it hits getContextMenu, I get error at line Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu.  error is uncaught error: no type specified for controller.create.  any idea?

Comment: Yes - fixed my answer :) changed from a basic object to actually creating  a controller instance, normally if you specify as a basic object, you would include a type - by not doing this you end up with the error you described.

Comment: so I changed to controller: Ext.create('Ext.app.ViewController',{
                    parent: this
                }),... now I get this error Uncaught Error: No method named "onDownloadTopdayRecapContextButton" on Ext.app.ViewController  @Theo

Comment: I think controller: this .. might work... checking now

Comment: This will cause you problems when you then destroy a panel - I think I am confusing some configs on models and controllers, I will dig out my code where I have definately solve this problem and make sure the answer is correct before updating again!

Comment: you are correct, I thought it worked... but then when I do some other things I get an error.  its isolated to the code I just added with controller.

Comment: OK so updated my answer, and created a fiddle to check/demonstrate it works.

Comment: it works!!! thanks so much!, just wanted to double check... I am not causing a memory leak am i?

Comment: No you should not be creating a memory leak, because we are now adding the context menu to the view, it will get destroyed when the view does. and because we only create once from the controller - you wont end up creating multiple menus.

Comment: so one last thing... the position is all of a sudden way off.  meaning where the context menu pops up.  its always pretty far down and to the right of where the mouse was right clicked.  any ideas? @Theo

Comment: Ah yes this is now positioned relative to the grid body - I've updated the fiddle to use a grid and found a fix, you basically change `this.getContextMenu().showAt(e.getXY())` to `this.getContextMenu().show().setPagePosition(e.getXY())`

Comment: I looked inside the showAt method to understand what it was doing: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/src/Component.js-1.html#Ext.Component-method-showAt

Comment: much appreciated... I would never have seen that